# linux how to log all ping responses

Tags: logs, ping

in linux (RHEL / CentOS 7 specifically) is there a way, such as in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` to log all responses to `ping` ?

If somebody on the network pings my linux computer, is there a way to log that and at some later date know when that happened and from what IP address I was pinged from?

Answer (score 3):

First be sure tcpdump installed your system. Then create script file and add following command in script file.

```
sudo tcpdump -i ethX icmp and icmp[icmptype]=icmp-echo >> ping.log
```

Then add in cronjob this script file.

Comment: simply doing `tcpdump -i eth0 icmp and icmp[icmptype]=icmp-echo` does work but it seems that command has to always be active?  Is there a way to do this such that it happens behind the scenes automatically?  Otherwise I suppose I can manually run this command and have it always active and echoing to a given log file ?

Comment: it did report the time of the ping response, but did not include the date.  But I can accomplish that by echoing the date (month,day,year) to my log file every so often as needed.

Comment: @ron `ts` can be used to add a timestamp: pipe `tcpdump` to `ts`.

Comment: thanks, this tcpdump method was a good starting point that allowed me to find a solution to my liking.

Comment: the redirection via `>>` doesn't seem to work in RHEL 7.9.  `tcpdump` only works to standard output or using its `-w` flag.

Answer (score 1):

here is what I settled on doing that works well enough for me.

refer to `man tcpdump`

```
tcpdump  -U  -i eth0   icmp and icmp[icmptype]=icmp-echo   -C 10   -w /root/ping_`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M'`.log &
```

this saves to a binary log file per the `-w` with the date+time appended to the log file name for when the log file was started.

`-C` limits the log file to # megabytes

the `-U` is important because it causes a flush to file, without it you will never see contents in */root/ping.log* until you Ctrl-C the tcpdump.

To read the ping log, which is in binary format, `tcpdump` is required and is easily done via

```
tcpdump  -r <log file>  -tttt

tcpdump  -r <log file>  -tttt -n
```

*I could not get the `ts` from moreutils to work via pipe.  Also redirecting standard output from tcpdump via `>>` did not work either.  This is on RHEL 7.9*

To stop this background tcpdump process, I am doing a `ps -ef | grep tcpdump | grep root` to identify its PID then do a `kill -9 <PID>` on it.